# Class "mysqli" not found in ....db.driver.inc.php

Tags: php, mysqli

i've got a strange error message in my logs :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in
> ....db.driver.inc.php

Mysqli is installed for months but sometimes, the class is not found !!!
It occured seleveral times in the day and during a very short time.

Do you guys have any idea what's going on with this server ?

Comment: I guess the script was executed by CLI (or other sapis) but you hadn't configured mysqli for the corresponding php.ini.

Comment: @shingo the server is used all day long on production and sometimes i get this strange fatal error

Comment: It's possible that the `CLI`, mostly used by cronjobs, isn't using the same `INI` file as the handler that is serving your website. Are you using any cronjobs on your website?

Comment: @user1957351 I know, that's why I guess.

Comment: It's not the cronjob, I have 10000 request per day and 20 times per day it can't find the class